# Include an external solution in premake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, premake

I am trying to write a top level `premake4` script to build a project that has multiple external dependencies.

The external builds include things like Java and CMake that (as far as I can tell) premake does not understand. The script does generate an MS Visual Studio 2010 solution.  Is there a way to tell premake to include the projects in the solution, so that building inside Visual Studio will rebuild the external projects if they are out of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in Premake4 without extending it. But if you can use Premake5, it's easily done : https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/external

Builds for Premake5 are available here http://premake.github.io/ if you want to try it.